# How to convert lists nested in a tibble into a single tibble with each list item on a new row?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a tibble with this structure (`dput` below):

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
  Date  CC            Variance_Type
  <fct> <list>        <list>       
1 2-17  <dbl [8 x 2]> <chr [8]>    
2 2-18  <dbl [8 x 2]> <chr [8]>    
3 2-19  <dbl [8 x 2]> <chr [8]>    
4 2-20  <dbl [8 x 2]> <chr [8]>    
5 2-21  <dbl [8 x 2]> <chr [8]>    
6 2-22  <dbl [8 x 2]> <chr [8]>    
7 2-23  <dbl [8 x 2]> <chr [8]>
```

My desired output is a 56 row x 4 column tibble where:

1. The items of the lists have been unnested each to their own row.
2. The values in `Date` fill down the column to match the items that are presently in their row.
3. The columns of the nested tables in column `CC` are split into separate columns.

I've been trying to do this in the tidyverse with a combination of mutate(), map() and bind_rows() but I can't make it work. Any help is much appreciated.

The tibble:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(1:7, .Label = c("2-17", "2-18", 
"2-19", "2-20", "2-21", "2-22", "2-23"), class = "factor"), CC = list(
    structure(c(0.0292, 0.1803, 0.1063, 0.3555, 0.0227, 0.0471, 
    0.2588, 1, 2.92, 18.03, 10.63, 35.55, 2.27, 4.71, 25.88, 
    100), .Dim = c(8L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("Unique to Jsc             ", 
    "Unique to Uoc             ", "Unique to FF              ", 
    "Common to Jsc, and Uoc    ", "Common to Jsc, and FF     ", 
    "Common to Uoc, and FF     ", "Common to Jsc, Uoc, and FF", 
    "Total                     "), c("Coefficient", "    % Total"
    ))), structure(c(0.0414, 0.2307, 0.1813, 0.3428, 0.0408, 
    0.0137, 0.1494, 1, 4.14, 23.07, 18.13, 34.28, 4.08, 1.37, 
    14.94, 100), .Dim = c(8L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("Unique to Jsc             ", 
    "Unique to Uoc             ", "Unique to FF              ", 
    "Common to Jsc, and Uoc    ", "Common to Jsc, and FF     ", 
    "Common to Uoc, and FF     ", "Common to Jsc, Uoc, and FF", 
    "Total                     "), c("Coefficient", "    % Total"
    ))), structure(c(0.0348, 0.2298, 0.4534, 0.0453, 0.1252, 
    0.0406, 0.0709, 1, 3.48, 22.98, 45.34, 4.53, 12.52, 4.06, 
    7.09, 100), .Dim = c(8L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("Unique to Jsc             ", 
    "Unique to Uoc             ", "Unique to FF              ", 
    "Common to Jsc, and Uoc    ", "Common to Jsc, and FF     ", 
    "Common to Uoc, and FF     ", "Common to Jsc, Uoc, and FF", 
    "Total                     "), c("Coefficient", "    % Total"
    ))), structure(c(0.0693, 0.1241, 0.3104, 0.0885, 0.1706, 
    0.0563, 0.1807, 1, 6.93, 12.41, 31.04, 8.85, 17.06, 5.63, 
    18.07, 100), .Dim = c(8L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("Unique to Jsc             ", 
    "Unique to Uoc             ", "Unique to FF              ", 
    "Common to Jsc, and Uoc    ", "Common to Jsc, and FF     ", 
    "Common to Uoc, and FF     ", "Common to Jsc, Uoc, and FF", 
    "Total                     "), c("Coefficient", "    % Total"
    ))), structure(c(0.0431, 0.1621, 0.3896, 0.2243, 0.1005, 
    -0.0339, 0.1143, 1, 4.31, 16.21, 38.96, 22.43, 10.05, -3.39, 
    11.43, 100), .Dim = c(8L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("Unique to Jsc             ", 
    "Unique to Uoc             ", "Unique to FF              ", 
    "Common to Jsc, and Uoc    ", "Common to Jsc, and FF     ", 
    "Common to Uoc, and FF     ", "Common to Jsc, Uoc, and FF", 
    "Total                     "), c("Coefficient", "    % Total"
    ))), structure(c(0.0656, 0.1021, 0.2638, 0.1299, 0.2102, 
    0.0061, 0.2223, 1, 6.56, 10.21, 26.38, 12.99, 21.02, 0.61, 
    22.23, 100), .Dim = c(8L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("Unique to Jsc             ", 
    "Unique to Uoc             ", "Unique to FF              ", 
    "Common to Jsc, and Uoc    ", "Common to Jsc, and FF     ", 
    "Common to Uoc, and FF     ", "Common to Jsc, Uoc, and FF", 
    "Total                     "), c("Coefficient", "    % Total"
    ))), structure(c(0.0802, 0.1114, 0.6962, 0.0845, 0.1544, 
    -0.0958, -0.0309, 1, 8.02, 11.14, 69.62, 8.45, 15.44, -9.58, 
    -3.09, 100), .Dim = c(8L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("Unique to Jsc             ", 
    "Unique to Uoc             ", "Unique to FF              ", 
    "Common to Jsc, and Uoc    ", "Common to Jsc, and FF     ", 
    "Common to Uoc, and FF     ", "Common to Jsc, Uoc, and FF", 
    "Total                     "), c("Coefficient", "    % Total"
    )))), Variance_Type = list(c("Unique to Jsc             ", 
"Unique to Uoc             ", "Unique to FF              ", "Common to Jsc, and Uoc    ", 
"Common to Jsc, and FF     ", "Common to Uoc, and FF     ", "Common to Jsc, Uoc, and FF", 
"Total                     "), c("Unique to Jsc             ", 
"Unique to Uoc             ", "Unique to FF              ", "Common to Jsc, and Uoc    ", 
"Common to Jsc, and FF     ", "Common to Uoc, and FF     ", "Common to Jsc, Uoc, and FF", 
"Total                     "), c("Unique to Jsc             ", 
"Unique to Uoc             ", "Unique to FF              ", "Common to Jsc, and Uoc    ", 
"Common to Jsc, and FF     ", "Common to Uoc, and FF     ", "Common to Jsc, Uoc, and FF", 
"Total                     "), c("Unique to Jsc             ", 
"Unique to Uoc             ", "Unique to FF              ", "Common to Jsc, and Uoc    ", 
"Common to Jsc, and FF     ", "Common to Uoc, and FF     ", "Common to Jsc, Uoc, and FF", 
"Total                     "), c("Unique to Jsc             ", 
"Unique to Uoc             ", "Unique to FF              ", "Common to Jsc, and Uoc    ", 
"Common to Jsc, and FF     ", "Common to Uoc, and FF     ", "Common to Jsc, Uoc, and FF", 
"Total                     "), c("Unique to Jsc             ", 
"Unique to Uoc             ", "Unique to FF              ", "Common to Jsc, and Uoc    ", 
"Common to Jsc, and FF     ", "Common to Uoc, and FF     ", "Common to Jsc, Uoc, and FF", 
"Total                     "), c("Unique to Jsc             ", 
"Unique to Uoc             ", "Unique to FF              ", "Common to Jsc, and Uoc    ", 
"Common to Jsc, and FF     ", "Common to Uoc, and FF     ", "Common to Jsc, Uoc, and FF", 
"Total                     "))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Answer (score 0):

While this is generally the type of problem that `unnest()` from **tidyr** will help with, your `CC` variable is a matrix instead of a data.frame (or tibble).  This causes some problems.  Once you convert the matrix to a data.frame, I think you'll find `unnest()` to be the go-to tool.

My first step was then to loop through the matrices in `CC` and convert them to data.frames, using a purrr::map loop within `mutate()`.  Then I use `unnest()` to unnest both variables at one time.

Here's how this works post **tidyr** version 1.0.0.

```
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
     mutate(CC = map(CC, as.data.frame) ) %>%
     unnest(cols = c(CC, Variance_Type) )

# A tibble: 56 x 4
   Date  Coefficient `    % Total` Variance_Type               
   <fct>       <dbl>         <dbl> <chr>                       
 1 2-17       0.0292          2.92 "Unique to Jsc             "
 2 2-17       0.180          18.0  "Unique to Uoc             "
 3 2-17       0.106          10.6  "Unique to FF              "
 4 2-17       0.356          35.6  "Common to Jsc, and Uoc    "
 5 2-17       0.0227          2.27 "Common to Jsc, and FF     "
 6 2-17       0.0471          4.71 "Common to Uoc, and FF     "
 7 2-17       0.259          25.9  Common to Jsc, Uoc, and FF  
 8 2-17       1             100    "Total                     "
 9 2-18       0.0414          4.14 "Unique to Jsc             "
10 2-18       0.231          23.1  "Unique to Uoc             "
```

For previous versions of **tidyr**, the `unnest()` code looks slightly different.

```
dat %>%
     mutate(CC = map(CC, as.data.frame) ) %>%
     unnest(CC, Variance_Type )
```

Comment: With your `unnest((cols = c(CC, Variance_Type))` I get ```Error: Column `cols` must be length 7 (the number of rows) or one, not 14```. But if I delete the `cols` argument it works perfectly.

Comment: I'll check this again. Is your tidyr version current?

Comment: Ah, I have tidyr 0.8.3, so no actually. I am managing packages with Conda so I think I am behind.

Comment: Oh, that must be it. Unnest changed a bit in tidyr version 1.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution based on `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
df2 <- setDT(df)[, as.data.table(.SD$CC[[1]], .SD[["Variance_Type"]]), Date]
setnames(df2, "rn", "Variance_Type")

df2
#       Date              Variance_Type Coefficient     % Total
#  1:   2-17 Unique to Jsc                   0.0292        2.92
#  2:   2-17 Unique to Uoc                   0.1803       18.03
#  3:   2-17 Unique to FF                    0.1063       10.63
#  4:   2-17 Common to Jsc, and Uoc          0.3555       35.55
#  5:   2-17 Common to Jsc, and FF           0.0227        2.27
#  6:   2-17 Common to Uoc, and FF           0.0471        4.71
#  7:   2-17 Common to Jsc, Uoc, and FF      0.2588       25.88
#  8:   2-17 Total                           1.0000      100.00
#  9:   2-18 Unique to Jsc                   0.0414        4.14
# 10:   2-18 Unique to Uoc                   0.2307       23.07
# 11:   2-18 Unique to FF                    0.1813       18.13
# 12:   2-18 Common to Jsc, and Uoc          0.3428       34.28
# 13:   2-18 Common to Jsc, and FF           0.0408        4.08
# 14:   2-18 Common to Uoc, and FF           0.0137        1.37
# 15:   2-18 Common to Jsc, Uoc, and FF      0.1494       14.94
# 16:   2-18 Total                           1.0000      100.00
# 17:   2-19 Unique to Jsc                   0.0348        3.48
# 18:   2-19 Unique to Uoc                   0.2298       22.98
# 19:   2-19 Unique to FF                    0.4534       45.34
# 20:   2-19 Common to Jsc, and Uoc          0.0453        4.53
# 21:   2-19 Common to Jsc, and FF           0.1252       12.52
# 22:   2-19 Common to Uoc, and FF           0.0406        4.06
# 23:   2-19 Common to Jsc, Uoc, and FF      0.0709        7.09
# ....
```